# how fix roundig operation in swift

Tags: calculator, multiplication, division, operation

I'm new to swift.
I usually use other languages, I made a calculator but I have a problem with some operations, for example when I print (1666.66 * 10) it prints 16666.60 ... 02 can you tell me why and how to fix it?
thanks